# Copy/paste data into consolidated list

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck on how to structure a piece of code that:

1. Loops through all worksheets that begin with the number 673: (e.g. 673:green, 673:blue)
2. Selects the data in these worksheets from row 5 up until the last row with data - code that works for this (generously provided by another user) is

   ```
   Dim report As Worksheet
   Set report = Excel.ActiveSheet    

   With report
   .Range(.Cells(5, "K"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Select
   End With
   ```
3. Select the "Colours" worksheet
4. Paste the rows at the next available blank row. There could be up to 40/50 worksheets which will have data pasted into the "Colours" worksheet so I need the data added to the next available line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Have you tried using the Macro recorder? Turn it on, do your steps, then look at the code.  This isn't too complicated, so hopefully you can get there with the recorder. If not, please let us know what you've tried and where it isn't working.

Comment: Hi, this wouldn't be possible with a macro recorder as it would need to loop through all worksheets that begin with "673". The number of these sheets is not fixed. Thanks

Comment: The loop won't be recorded, but your Selecting the sheets, pasting rows, etc. will.  Then, you just had to add a loop around that, and create a `lastRow` variable for your WS. From the code you showed, you only are selecting stuff...where's the rest?

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop over the sheets in the workbook and check their names

   ```
   For Each sheet in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If Instr(sheet.Name,"673")>0 Then
           ...
       End If
   Next
   ```
2. Good, but you're going to want to copy.

   ```
   Selection.Copy
   ```
3. Just select.

   ```
   Worksheets("Colours").Select
   ```
4. Find the last row then go to the next. The row is found by finding the first populated row from the bottom up. Note I used explicit sheet references, which is unnecessary since you selected the sheet already. This is better form, however, if you will be manipulating data on multiple sheets in your code.

   ```
   lastRow = Worksheets("Colours").Cells(Worksheets("Colours").rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
   Worksheets("Colours").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
   Activesheet.Paste
   ```